# How to retrieve all fields whose table belongs to a model and access them with object reference of that model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-4

I want to develop proprietary MVC framework in PHP and understand OOP concepts in crystal clear manner. I stuck  right here. First look at code snippet....

```
// main model class
class Model{
    protected static $table;
    protected static $primary_key;
    protected static $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // variable calling from configuration file
        global $defalult_database_engine,$connections;
        self::dbConnection();
        // query to fetch all columns name belo
        $query="SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =? AND TABLE_NAME =?";
        $stmt=self::$conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array($connections['mysql']['database'],'users'));
        $fields=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        foreach($fields as $field)
        {
            $fileldname=$field->COLUMN_NAME;
            // creating variable name to matching to the tables fields name
            // how to set value of this variable via object
            $$fileldname;
        }
    }
```

And child model is like this

```
class Users extends Model
{
    protected static $table='users';
}
```

now turn for controller

```
class UserController extends Controller{
     public function __construct(){
     }

     public function createUser(){
        // user model
        $user=new Users();
        // calling attributes of the table and set their value
        $user->name='full name';
        $user->user_name='user name';
        $user->password='password';
        // finally save the value of fields
        $user->save();            
     }
}
```

I want to work in above fashion. I convert tables' field names to the variable but unable to reference it via its object.... exactly same way in UserController given above. Is there any idea to make it possible? actually I am currently working in Laravel 4.2 and influenced;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to retrieve field details from table; instead of retrieving we must take benefit of  dynamic instance variable;which can be generated in php like following code,

```
$user->user_name; // $user_name variable has been created dynamically and bolongs to the $user table
$user->user_name='your user_name'; // value assigned to dynamic instance variable
$user->save();// this function is defined to the model class
```

and the code for save() of main model should like as follows:

```
public function save()
{
   $datainfo = (array)$this // this assing the array to the $datainfo variable with all dynamic instance variable
   // do your manipulation with data received in $datainfo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to recreate Laravel's syntax -- sounds like a fun project.

Laravel utilizes PHP's [__get() magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) to create an array of model attributes.

Here's the source code for Laravel's __get and getAttribute methods:

```
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->getAttribute($key);
}
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes) || $this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
        return $this->getAttributeValue($key);
    }

    return $this->getRelationValue($key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your comment... you feel it like fun but its crucial to me to improve myself.. eventually i found its solution; solution is really simple but hard to think such fashion who are familiar with other programming language.

    $user->user_name //create an dynamic instance variable
    $instances=(array)$this // this code convert your object in an array

Comment: Glad to help. If you found it helpful, please upvote or mark it as complete. Thanks and best wishes on your project and personal growth!

Comment: No matter it is helpful or not to me i will up vote it; what matter is how you are really helpful thanks sirji.